# Get time (hour, minute) from a non-local ISO8601 string with moment

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, datetime, momentjs

I would like to get the time of an ISO8601 string in the specified timezone.

However, whenever I grab the moment object of the ISO8601 string, it converts everything to my machine's local time.

E.g. when I do `moment("2015-09-15T07:55+02:00").hours()`, it returns 1 since it converted it to `2015-09-15T01:55:00-04:00"`.

How do I make it so that it returns 7 for hours?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help:

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/special-formats/

```
moment("2010-01-01T05:06:07", moment.ISO_8601);
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure about moment, but here's my converter for the eastern time zone, if it helps...

```
getServerDate: function(dateValue) {
    var dateJan;
    var dateJul;
    var timezoneOffset;

    // Get dates for January and July
    dateJan = new Date(dateValue.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
    dateJul = new Date(dateValue.getFullYear(), 6, 1);

    // Get timezone offset
    timezoneOffset = Math.max(dateJan.getTimezoneOffset(), dateJul.getTimezoneOffset());

    // Check if daylight savings
    if (dateValue.getTimezoneOffset() < timezoneOffset) {
      // Adjust date by 4 hours
      dateValue = new Date(dateValue.getTime() + ((1 * 60 * 60 * 1000) * 4));
    } else {
      // Adjust date by 5 hours
      dateValue = new Date(dateValue.getTime() + ((1 * 60 * 60 * 1000) * 5));
    }

    return dateValue;
},
```